# Stack Overflow error on one PC, no errors on the other?

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow

The problem is this:

I have a project developed in Delphi XE on my laptop. When I run it on my desktop PC, I get a "stack overflow" exception on this line (I also used Writeln() on different parts of the code and just this line is the source of the problem):

`S_List.LoadFromFile('Test.txt');`

(S_List is a local TStringList which is created before this line)

But, when I run the same exact project on my laptop, it works without any errors or exceptions at all. The problem can't be the method itself, because when I change the whole part and write it again using 'TStreamReader', the same exception occurs. This time on `StreamReader.ReadLine()`. Also, I changed the file location, name, .... Problem still occurs.

It seems like a file system problem, but I don't have the slightest idea how this happens.

Any ideas? Can it be because of a virus or a malware?

P.S: Both (laptop and PC) have Win7 and Delphi XE. Also, both have 2GB RAM.

Edit: Just to be clear, my main goal for asking this question is not finding where the exception lies (that can't happen by giving 1 line of code, can it?). But, instead, how come this error is NOT consistant in different hardwares? What reason can that have? Also, how can I find what causes this inconsistency?

Comment: Surely you mean `S_List.LoadFromFile` instead of `S_List:= LoadFromFile`.

Comment: Oops! Yeah, You're right. Question edited. Thanks.

Comment: Probably the list is very long and on your laptop you have more RAM than on your desktop...

Comment: I doubt that an out of memory can cause a stack overflow exception. I also doubt that the problem is really with this line. It might be helpfule to show more code.

Comment: Indeed, in the vast majority of cases, I believe, 'out of memory' errors (that come as a surprise to the developer) are actually not caused by a too small amount of memory.

Comment: Stack overflows usually result from direct or indirect recursion run wild. He could e.g. run code in an event handler that, indirectly, causes the event handler to be called again. It must not be the line itself that is the culprit.

Comment: @Rudy, The reason I tell that this line causes the problem is that when I comment it, the project works completely fine. Also, even when the file has 3 lines, exception persists. And, the project has no recursion at all. it is just a simple method calling.

Comment: If method A does something that causes method B to be called, which calls method C which calls method A again, you have indirect recursion. Most "stack overflow" messages result from something like this. Or from trashing the stack pointer.

Comment: TStringList.LoadFromFile causes stack overflow? I don't think so. Dig deeper.

Comment: That's strange. I'm [fighting today with a stack overflow](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=2491#p2491) with no recursive call. The same program works with Delphi 7, 2007, but not with 2010 nor XE. I run it under FullDebugMode and there is no memory corruption nor leak reported... I don't think it's Unicode related. And I don't use any `TStringList` here, just make a huge use of memory allocations... is it your case?

Comment: Are both systems fitted with 64-bit OS or is the bitness different (32 and 64 bit)?

Comment: @Arnaud, Totally strange. My case is in some ways like yours. I get the exception no matter how I access the file (using StreamReader, ...). Also, I have lots of memory allocations in my project and even some pointers. BTW, The file I try to read is ANSI formatted.So,... What do you think?

Comment: @The_Fox, Both systems has 32-bit OS.

Comment: @David: I don't think LoadFromFile causes a stack overflow, it must be some kind of recursion. Or it is an error in a recent Windows update. <g>

Comment: The more I read, the more I think it could be a hardware or HDD driver problem.

Comment: @Flom Take a look [here](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=2498#p2498) at my testing: it does not depend on the PC in my case, just on the compiler used... difficult to trace such errors. In my case, I tend to link it to some uninitialized objects as I already encountered [here with Delphi 2010](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/01/29/record-and-object-issue-in-Delphi-2010). Do you use any objects instead of classes?

Comment: @Arnaud, I don't use objects, just records and classes. Of course, I have many records with strings or dynamic variables in them. They are the usual suspects in memory-related exceptions, aren't they?

Answer (score 4):

My guess, and guessing is all we can do, is that you have an uninitialised local variable. Or an object that you access after having freed it. I'm not sure how that leads to your stack overflow but almost anything is possible with such a scenario. As well as madExcept you should be using FastMM with full debug settings.

Comment: +1 Usually those mad error which happen to be no reason and spent me so much time finding is some variables I take it for granted for their "default" value.

Comment: +1 It is a fair assumption. I have this bad habit not to initialize the variables (or even big record instances). I will surely check them. @Justmade, Me 2!

Answer (score 2):

When someone has difficulty diagnosing an exception in a specific environment with a Delphi application I strongly suggest [madExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm). It's free for non-commercial use, very easy to setup, and VERY helpful. Install it, enable it for your project, build a debug build, and deploy it to the problem machine. When the exception occurs, you should get a very detailed call stack of where the issue happened.

Comment: I doubt that helps. Because, I know exactly what the call stack is and by using many writeln's, narrowed it down to this line. Also, when I comment just this line, exception goes away.

Comment: EurekaLog is an equally useful alternative to madExcept.

Answer (score 2):

I would check this:

1. Is the test file identical on both computers
2. Do you have the same locale settings on both computers
3. If Delphi XE has components source, debug TStringList source, maybe there is a bug
4. As Nathanial suggested, use madExcept or similar library
5. Create simple program that will just allocate TStringList and load test file. If this works, bug is somewhere else in your code, if this fails bug is probably in TStringList

Comment: Actually, I tested the same thing with a simple program and got no exception. So, definitely it is this project and has nothing to do with TStringList (or TStreamReader for that matter) but with working with a file. Then again, why does it happen on just one computer?

Comment: Try looking at the list zendar posted and try those.  If you create a simple program with TStringList and load this file and it works, then it has to do with your program.  Also: 6. How much data is in this file ('Test.txt') and how is it formatted?

Comment: @Glenn, From the zender's list, I just don't know how to check #2. Also, somehow I can't get madExcept to work, so #4 is out (I guess that's another question by itself!). As I mentioned in my comment to the question, even when the file has just 1 line(!) I get the exception (the file is a simple ANSI txt).

Comment: There is no bug in TStringList.LoadFromFile or .LoadFromStream. I am slowly thinking of a hardware error.

Answer (score 0):

Check for duplicate DCU's and if possible do a full build of installed libraries and the application to see if the error persists.